# i have a question about fgets and related in C

Tags: c, scanf, fgets

```
char *ch;   
ch = fgets(buffer, 100, file);
printf("%s1\n", ch);   
printf("A(x) = ");  
while (!feof(file)) { 
    if (fscanf(file, "(%d,%d)", &a[i].coef, &a[i].exp) != 2) {
```

I have this code and I'm trying to write poly A. but when I run this, I get second row of input for A. There is no problem when I print ch, but there is problem when I'm trying to print A.
The input is:

```
(5,2)(4,6)(5,7)(7,3)(1,0)(9,1)(5,5)
(5,1)(8,0)(8,6)(3,5)(1,3)(7,2)(9,7)(5,4)
```

I want the first row to be in A.

I tried to change `fscanf(file)` but I wasn't able to fix it.

Comment: woo, can you correct your code? It seems to be incomplete.

Comment: Please ensure you have an [mcve], which people can test. That includes a simple test input file.

Comment: "but there is problem". So, what is the problem? You mention you have a problem, but you don't state what the exact problem is. Please state the precise problem, including errors, incorrect (and expected) output, warnings etc.

Comment: The problem *might* be that `buffer` isn't allocated correctly.  But we can't see the declaration for that variable, so we can't tell.

Comment: One problem is definitely your use of `feof`.  See [Why is `while( !feof(file) )` always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941)